# sqlpackage.exe with domain user

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-devops

I have a script I run in powershell. I use a sql login with username and passowrd, instead of doing that I would like to use a domain user with username and password.

```
sqlpackage.exe /SourceFile:"<location of dacpac>" /Action:Publish /TargetServerName:"server" /TargetDatabaseName:"database" /TargetUser:"Deployment" /TargetPassword:"pass"
```

I want insted of "/TargetUser:"Deployment" /TargetPassword:"pass"" I would like to know how to translate this to the sql command.

```
Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=domain\user;Password=pass1;
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `sqlpackage.exe`? It tells you exactly how to specify a connection string.

Comment: I did read and I try to change add the /SourceConnectionString: 10 different ways, and it is not working. I am not sure how.

Comment: "Not working" is too vague to provide you with any help. What was the **exact** error message?

Comment: I am not sure how to build the command, that is my issue. I have the following code: sqlpackage.exe /SourceFile:"<soure.dacpac>" /Action:Publish /TargetConnectionString:"Server=<server>;Database=<database>;Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=<domain user>;Password=<password>;" but it is bypassing the username and password and I get the following error: You must have a user with the same password in master or target server

Answer (score 1):

The `Integrated Security=SSPI` means using **windows authentication** and you don’t need to specify User Id and Password, also will be ignored if specified.

For windows authentication, it uses current user, so the build agent should be running as the corresponding user, who has the permission to publish database to sql server. (Change service’s Log On As account)

Otherwise, you need to use SQL authentication (`Integrated Security=false;UserId=xxx;Password=xxx`)

Comment: Yes, that is what I read before, and I was trying to work around that, I am deploying from vsts and I was trying to use a domain user, so I don't need to change username and password.

Comment: @Astrid Not clear what said, do you mean you want to do it without change agent's account?